# Finding very high cumulative Poisson probabilities?

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

I have to find the probability of a Poisson distributed problem where the average rate of success is 40 and I need to find the probability of something being > 50.

Normally I'd just either add the probabilities together manually or look at Poisson probability tables.

But adding 50 probability calculations together manually takes a while. And the tables only go up to 15.

So how do you find the probability when you are dealing with "large" numbers.

Answer (score 5):

There's a direct connection between the Poisson and the chi-squared distributions.

See for example, the first few lines of Johnson (1959) [1] which gives a direct derivation (before extending what was then already a known result). This fact can also be seen in the Wikipedia article on the Poisson distribution.

If I have this right, given $Y\sim \text{Pois}(\lambda)$ then for $X\sim$ chi-squared with $\nu=2y$, we have $P(Y\geq y) = P(X<2\lambda)$.

---

If the Poisson mean is not too small and a reasonably close approximation suffices, the [Anscombe transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anscombe_transform) can often be useful.

[1] N. L. Johnson (1959),
"On an Extension of the Connexion Between Poisson and χ2 Distributions,"
*Biometrika*, Vol. 46, No. 3/4 (Dec.), pp. 352-363

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't necessarily call this "very high" probabilities. I'd reserve that label for situations where we have to think about numerical accuracy, which doesn't really come into play here yet.

The solution in your case: [install R](https://www.r-project.org/) and type:

```
> 1-ppois(50,40,lower.tail=TRUE)
[1] 0.05262805
```

Look at `?ppois` for the help page.

Comment: I know the answer to the question.

But I need to learn the method behind calculating it. Not just having it computed.

Thanks for the title edit though, that is correct :)

Comment: Ah. But the method *will* usually be just to add [Poisson probabilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) (and having a computer do it). Are you looking for the Poisson probability mass function? That is $$\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}e^{-\lambda}$$ for parameter $\lambda$ and outcome $k$ - you'd add this up for your $\lambda=40$ and $k=0, \dots, 50$. Or are you in fact interested in the numerics? I think I may not be understanding your question completely...

Comment: Well in this case, it's an exercise we are supposed to do with pen and paper and a simple calculator. So using advanced computing like ppois functions isn't an option. It's still possible to add them together manually of course, but that doesn't seem right with such large numbers. So I just assumed there was another way to calculate it?

The actual problem. Is a sample of 100 within a time interval, where 40% is the  average success rate, and I need to figure out the probability of 50% or more. So the data should be correct to do it? Unless I'm missing something...

Comment: I wouldn't use a Poisson distribution for a success rate. The Poisson is discrete and unbounded. You'd rather use a beta distribution, which is bounded to the interval $[0,1]$. Or, if you explicitly have 100 trials (and not only success *rates*), you may want to look at the [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution), which may be enlightening.

Comment: Are you allowed to use another distribution method when you are given a time interval? It states specifically that you normally get 100 contacts within a week. It doesn't just say 100 trials. It makes it pretty clear that it's Poisson distributed?

Comment: You'd typically use the Poisson distribution for a *number* (like a number of contacts) that is, in principle, unbounded. If you have underlying *trials* (like $n$ phone contacts) and are interested in how many of these trials resulted in a *success* (e.g., a sale), you'd use a binomial distribution.

Comment: Interesting. It sounds like it's cumulative binomial distribution I need to look at then. But isn't there still the problem of needing to add together 50 probabilities?

Comment: As I said, reading up on the binomial distribution should be enlightening...